# Disable SpeechRecognitionCore

Tags: services, macos

**edit:** I don't use this feature, don't need nor want it running in the background.

Is there a way to deactivate the service?

[image]

I've seen so far this command:

```
killall -9 com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond
```

But wouldn't like having to remember doing so manually.

Comment: Did you disable Dictation in System Preferences? Mine is disabled and that process is not even running on my system. ([This thread](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120039/why-does-speech-recognition-take-up-1-gm-or-ram-suddenly-and-gmail-in-safari-73) also suggests that simply disabling Enhanced Dictation, while leaving Dictation on, will greatly reduce its memory footprint.)

Comment: Virtual memory is free. The actual memory allocations look fine. What precisely is the problem other than you're surprised that the virtual count is so high?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, edited the question as I didn't have a good question format before.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have Dictation enabled.

[image: Dictation setting]

This setting is under Keyboard System Preferences.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with that process using 800 MB of real memory.

On three OS X machines I surveyed: 5 MB of shared, 825 MB private and 865 MB of real memory was typical. The virtual memory ranged between 3.0 and 4.0 GB.

What's important is the overall memory pressure on the system. Here you can see that speech recognition does have one of the larger footprints, but the system was in no way over committed with respect to RAM.

[image]

Since the process doesn't even start until you dictate, killing it won't really do much if you continue to use that feature. Since it is run on a per-user basis, logging out and back it will release the memory it uses and you can continue killing it as well, but there'd need to be other issues for this allocation to cause problems on a system.

Answer (score 0):

To kill the process:

Go to: Preferences/Accessibility/Siri/Open Siri Preferences. Then Disable "Ask Siri. The app will go away.